# Smooth vector bundles over contractible smooth manifolds with or without boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, manifolds-with-boundary

First, let me just write down the definitions I will use (see e.g. Lee - Introduction to Smooth Manifolds):

- Two (real) vector bundles $(E,B,\pi)$ and $(E',B,\pi')$ (over the same base space $B$) are **isomorphic** if there exists a homeomorphism $f: E \to E'$ such that $\pi = \pi' \circ f$ and such that the restriction of $f$ to each fiber is a linear map.
- A vector bundle $(E,B,\pi)$ is a **smooth vector bundle** if

  - $E$ and $B$ are smooth manifolds with or without boundary,
  - $\pi$ is a smooth map,
  - local trivializations are diffeomorphisms.

  Two smooth vector bundles $(E,B,\pi)$ and $(E',B,\pi')$ are **smoothly isomorphic** if there exists a diffeomorphism $f: E \to E'$ such that $\pi = \pi' \circ f$ and such that the restriction of $f$ to each fiber is a linear map.

Now, I heard about the following theorem:

*Let $(E,B,\pi)$ be a vector bundle. If $B$ is a contractible paracompact space, then $(E,B,\pi)$ is isomorphic to the trivial bundle $(E \times B,B,p)$ (where $p: E \times B \to B$ is the usual projection).*

**I have two questions:**

**1-** Does this theorem still holds with smooth vector bundles ? I.e.:

*Let $(E,B,\pi)$ be a smooth vector bundle. If $B$ is a contractible paracompact space, then $(E,B,\pi)$ is smoothly isomorphic to the trivial bundle $(E \times B,B,p)$.*

**2-** If this is the case, does this theorem still holds with manifolds with corners (i.e. if we replace "$E$ and $B$ are smooth manifolds with or without boundary" by "$E$ and $B$ are smooth manifolds with corners" in the definition of a smooth vector bundle) ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Small correction: the definition of isomorphic vector bundles includes the additional requirement that the homeomorphism $f$ restricts to a linear map on each fiber.

Comment: @JackLee Sorry, I was sloppy. I saw that you talk a little bit about smooth manifolds with corners in your book (and it is really nice, because I don't find many things on that subject), would you have any clue for my problem ?

Comment: Yes, it holds for smooth manifolds, with or without boundaries or corners. I don't have a reference handy, but here's an outline of the proof. First use the topological result to find a continuous bundle isomorphism. Then you can use a version of the Whitney approximation theorem, one local trivialization at a time, to replace the continuous isomorphism by a smooth one.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I appreciate !